# C++ programming question

Tags: c++

Can Someone tell me what I am doing wrong I have tried my best with this program, please someone with a little more time on their hands so that they can take time to look at the program and Help! Thank you all for your time:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

//function prototypes
void getItemNumber ();
void checkItemNumber (char *, int);

int main()
{
   //declare variables
   string Item = ""; 
   getItemNumber(); 
   checkItemNumber(item);


   //call function to get input

   //void getItemNumber ();
   //void checkItemNumber (item);
   cout << "Enter your 5-digit item #: ";
   cin >> item;

   while (item.length() != 5)
   {
       cout << "Invalid item #. Please enter a 5-digit item # ";
       getline(cin, item);
   }

   if (item.length() == 5)
   {
       if ('B' == toupper(item[2])) 
           cout << "Your color is blue" << endl;
       else if ('G' == toupper(item[2])) 
           cout << "Your color is green" << endl;
       else if ('R' == toupper(item[2]))
           cout << "Your color is red" << endl;
       else if ('W' == toupper(item[2]))
           cout << "Your color is white" << endl;
   }
   else
       cout<< "Invalid name no matching color..."; 
       // if code is not from any of the above.

   system("pause");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is my code coming out all jumbled up when I typed it in correctly?

Comment: use verbose mode, here, i'll give you a hand...

Comment: Because code should be indented by four spaces.

Comment: looks like gf beat me to the punch. :-)

Comment: Please tag this question as "homework" if it is indeed a homework assignment.

Comment: Also, please try to be a bit more descriptive in your question titles than "[Language] Question". It also helps if you can tell us what's not working (Won't compile with errors, output is x but should be y, etc.)

Comment: I agree with other's comment. You should have a look at http://www.gerv.net/hacking/how-to-ask-good-questions. See points 6, 7, 8, 9 on how to ask a question. The way you ask it we can't even know if the code is not compiling, not working, and if not working what you expected it to do and what it actually do. We have to guess all of the above reading the program. Well, somes call that 'Guru documentation'. In your case the program is so simple that I believe we could actually answer, but I believe that if you ask it right you will also be able to answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get the point of the question, but there is a definite bug (in my opinion) in the code as it appears above.

Ask yourself under what conditions will the error message get printed out? In other words, what "if" does the "else" belong to?

Answer (score 0):

you need `#include <ctype>` for tolower.

the functions getItemNumber and checkItemNumber are not defined by any C standard, you should ask the one from which you got the code where getItemNumber and checkItemNumber are defined.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment "Modify the following code so that it uses separate functions getItemNumber and checkItemNumber".  Presumably defining the functions is part of the assignment.

Comment: The OP has included cctype, which provides C++ wrappers for ctype.h C functions. See this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/

Comment: Okay, but it's still not <ctype>.

Comment: @Larry, very vague, this is my first time coding this program so I just need a clear example, that would be a great help like how exactly should I set it up, just use an example so that you do not feel as you are doing my homework for me.  Thanks:)

Comment: @codymanix, I am sorry I am little confused by your comment these two are C++ functions ???  Thanks!